# kubectl logs -f stops after 45.1mb of logs

Tags: kubectl

Running the following command on MacOS 12.5.1:

`kubectl logs -f {pod name} | tee save.log`

There's no more output after 45.1MB is written and I have to `^c` and rerun (the command doesn't exit).

I don't think this has to do with a limit on the OS side because the following writes well beyond said limit:

`cat /dev/urandom | tee a.log`

According to the docs, `kubectl logs` runs with `--limit-bytes=0` by default, which means no limit. I tried adding it in just to make sure, but no change:

`kubectl logs --limit-bytes=0 -f {pod name} | tee save.log`

Comment: If you try to use `kubectl logs -f {pod name} | wc -c` does it also report 45.1 MiB? If so, then the issue is likely in kubectl

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues It doesn't exit the `kubectl logs` command, it just doesn't show anymore outout, so `wc -c` doesn't show any output

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the client running the kubectl command, Kubectl must be hitting memory or CPU crunch. Consider checking the mem and CPU of the node from which you run the kubectl command.  If that also does not help, consider running kubectl with `strace` like `strace kubectl log -f ........` to see the last syscall made. Also, I have tested and written 200Mb worth of logs, and kubectl is still running.

Comment: @P.... thank you for your comment. CPU and RAM don't seem to change at all. I'm not able to run strace on MAC but I'll try to run on a Linux machine or maybe a different command.

Comment: Try `dtruss`, this might give you insight